# What lines of code can in include in my class so as to have a validation technique for both email and password?

Tags: java, android

I have written the following lines of code and i need to include an error validation check in it for both Email and Password. The output on the screen upon a wrong mail/password entry should be in the form of a `Toast.makeText()` format. So here is the code below

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
    public void clickRegister(View view) {

        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class));

    }

    private Button buttonSignin;
    private EditText emailAdd;
    private EditText passAdd;
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        firebaseAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser()!=null){
            //Remote control activity
            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),RemoteControl.class));
        }
        buttonSignin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.logIn);
        emailAdd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailAddress);
        passAdd = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passWord);

        buttonSignin.setOnClickListener(this);


    }
private void userLogin(){
        String email=emailAdd.getText().toString().trim();
        String password=passAdd.getText().toString().trim();
    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){
        //Email is empty!
        Toast.makeText(this,"Please Enter Email",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //Stop function from executing further
        return;
    }

    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password))
    {
        //Password is empty
        Toast.makeText(this,"Please Enter Password",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }


    firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                //start profile activity
                finish();
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),RemoteControl.class));
            }
        }
    });
}
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        if(view==buttonSignin)
        {
            userLogin();
        }

    }
}
```

I expect an output of `Incorrect Email` and `Incorrect password` for each line of bad entry in the form of a `Toast.maketext()`

Comment: Just for the record: you don't tell users about invalid email (except when it is malformed). An attacker should not be able to distinguish "I used an unknown email" from "I used a known email but a wrong password".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Firebase Auth documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuthException), firebase throws a `FirebaseAuthException` error.
The subclasses you are looking for here are:

- **FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException** - incase of an incorrect password
- **FirebaseAuthInvalidUserException** - incase of an account that does not exist

and apply it as:

```
firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
        if(task.isSuccessful()){
            //start profile activity
            finish();
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),RemoteControl.class));
        }

      else if(task.getException() instanceof 
             FirebaseAuthInvalidCredentialsException){
        Toast.makeText(context, "wrong password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else if(task.getException() instanceof FirebaseAuthInvalidUserException){
        Toast.makeText(context, "no user with such email", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    }
});
```

However as mentioned, you **don't** want to inform your users that an email does not exist but only inform them if the email is badly format, for that you can use a regex pattern as below:

```
if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){
    //Email is empty!
    Toast.makeText(this,"Please Enter Email",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    //Stop function from executing further
    return;
}
else if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()) {
    Toast.makeText(context,"Email is badly formatted",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

Comment: Can you implement it in the above code please..thanks

Comment: :) Thanks for the compliment, you can check the green tick if the answer helped you

Comment: Currently, I'm held up but you can reach me at deurola@gmail.com

Answer (score 1):

As per the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/password-auth), there is no way to tell whether there was an invalid email or an invalid password. You can only tell whether the sign-in process was successful or not and display an appropriate message like this-

```
mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                    Log.d(TAG, "signInWithEmail:success");
                    FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                    updateUI(user);
                } else {
                    // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                    Log.w(TAG, "signInWithEmail:failure", task.getException());
                    Toast.makeText(EmailPasswordActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    updateUI(null);
                }

                // ...
            }
        }
```

);

Firebase for Web, however, gives more flexibility to know where the error was with error codes like- auth/invalid-email, auth/email-already-in-use etc.